# Amazon WorkMail have emails go to two different addresses

Tags: email, mail-forwarding

Using Amazon WorkMail service we have an email address setup - lets say it's customerservice@domain.com . When someone sends that email address an email I would like the email to go to two different places.

1. To that actual email inbox
2. manager@domain.com

Is this possible? I think it is using the SES service but not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called email forwarding. Amazon has a guide [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/email-forwarding-rule-workmail/) which tells you how to set it up.

It's not clear from that page whether the email is delivered to both inboxes, or just the forwarded inbox. Try it and see. If it doesn't work report back and someone may have another solution for you.

Here's the current contents of the steps

1. Sign in to the Amazon WorkMail web application using the user account credentials for the account that you want to forward emails from.
   **Note**: To locate your Amazon WorkMail web application URL, open the Amazon WorkMail console and choose Organization settings from the left navigation pane. Under the General settings tab, select Web Application.
2. In the Amazon WorkMail web application, choose the gear icon in the top-right corner, select Email rules in the left navigation pane, and then choose New.
3. In the Rule name field, enter a name and ensure the Active rule check box is selected.
4. Under Conditions, select the drop-down menu and then choose is sent to … , choose Select recipient(s), select the user account that you want to forward email from, choose To, and then choose Ok.
   **Note**: You can choose other conditions such as received from ... , includes these words in the subject ... , etc.
5. Under Actions, select the drop-down menu and then choose Forward the message to … , choose Select recipient(s), enter the email address that you want to forward emails to in the To field, choose Ok, then choose Ok again to close the rule.
   **Note**: You can forward messages to an external email address, WorkMail users, resources, and groups, but not to personal Distribution Lists in your contact folder. Bounced emails will not be forwarded.
6. Choose Save changes.